# UIButton disabled when covered (or semi covered) by a view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a view that holds some UIButtons.  Another view covers and hides the buttons.  When the top view slides off to reveal the buttons (with an animation).. the UI draws the buttons grayed out until the top view no longer covers or overlaps the buttons at all.. causing an undesirable flicker from gray to the normal button color (white).

is there a way to keep the UIButton from rendering itself disabled while covered or semi covered by another view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in lieu of actually finding the correct answer, I simply swapped out the buttons with UIImageViews and attached UITapGestureRecognizers to them... this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that its correct that a button is disabled while covered. What is happening is that when its covered, touch events are prevented from getting to the button, so the button cant get pressed. If the button is only partially covered, touch events to that part that are not covered can be received by the button and the button can be depressed. If you really wanted the button to work while it was covered (maybe you can relayer your views so the button is in front of the view instead of behind it?) you could hack your view and void its hit testing so it doesnt capture the touches.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to touches.  I'm talking about the buttons appearance.    Touches have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I just tried it and my button doesnt change color when it was partially covered by another view. I wonder if you can dump these properties: state, enabled, selected, highlighted.

Comment: hmmm.. interesting. Mine are hosted in a UITableViewCell, by the way, and the "overlapping" view is another UITableviewcell, so, it must the the UITableView that is causing the "disabling" effect. that may give me something to go off.